# Given $\rho\in L(\mathcal H_A)$, can we find $\mathcal H_B\le \mathcal H_A$ such that ${\rm tr}_C(\rho)=\sigma$, for fixed $\sigma$?

Tags: quantum-state

Given an arbitrary density matrix $\rho \in L({\mathcal H_{A}})$, can one always find a subspace ${\mathcal H_{B}}$ of ${\mathcal H_{A}}$ such that ${\mathcal H_{A}}={\mathcal H_{B}}\otimes{\mathcal H_{C}}$ and ${\rm tr}_{C}(\rho)=\sigma$ for a fixed density matrix $\sigma \in L({\mathcal H_{B}})$?

While a purification of $\sigma$ yields a pure state $| \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |$ with the property ${\rm tr}_{C}(| \Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |)=\sigma$, I am wondering whether one can do the same given a fixed (possibly mixed) state $\rho$.

If this is possible, what would be the restrictions on the dimension of ${\mathcal H_{A}}$ (in relation to the size of ${\mathcal H_{C}}$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your question should be more carefully formulated, since it is not even possible to always find a non-trivial sub*system* (not sub*space*) of $\mathcal H_A$, see also my comment here [Can a single qutrit in superposition be considered entangled?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14049/can-a-single-qutrit-in-superposition-be-considered-entangled/14052#14052)

Thus, let us assume that $\mathcal H_A$ does not have prime dimension, $d_A=\dim\mathcal H_A$. The question should then be the following:
Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal H_B$ where $d_B=\dim\mathcal H_B$ divides $d_A$, and a density matrices $\rho\in\mathcal H_A$ and $\sigma\in\mathcal H_B$, is there a choice of tensor product $\mathcal H_A \simeq \mathcal H_B\otimes\mathcal H_C$, such that $\mathrm{tr}_C(\rho)=\sigma$.

I'm not so sure why you would call this a "purification", though.

This can sometimes be true. For example, take for simplicity $\mathcal H_B=\mathcal H_C=\mathbb C^d\otimes\mathbb C^d$ and define $\mathcal H_A := \mathcal H_B\otimes \mathcal H_C$.
Let $\phi^+$ be the standard maximally entangled state with respect to the bipartition of $\mathcal H_C=\mathcal H_B$.
Consider the product state $\rho=|\phi^+\rangle\langle\phi^+|\otimes|\phi^+\rangle\langle\phi^+|$, and $\sigma = \mathbb{I}/d^2$. Then there is always a different bipartition $A=B'|C'$ of $A$, such that $\mathrm{tr}_{C'}(\rho) = \sigma$. You can explicitly verify this by writing down the state and swapping the second tensor factors of $B$ and $C$.

**Update:**
However, in general, this is false since the partial trace make the state $\rho$ "more mixed". As pointed put by Danylo, the to states should fulfill some majorisation condition about their spectrum.

Here's a counter-example. Take $\rho = \mathbb{I}/d_A$. Then, for any choice of bipartition, $\mathrm{tr}_C(\rho) = \mathbb{I}/d_B$. Take $\sigma$ to be any other state, e.g. a pure one.

Comment: Entropy is not a correct indicator here, consider the case when $\rho$ is maximally mixed (then $\sigma$ is also maximally mixed but in a lower dimension, so $S(\sigma) < S(\rho)$).  
It has to be $\Lambda(\sigma) \prec \Lambda(\rho)$, i.e. the spectrum of $\sigma$ majorized by the spectrum of $\rho$.  And I think this is a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, the entropy depends on the dimension ... I was thinking about the spectrum in the first place and this seems very plausible!

Comment: $\Lambda(\sigma) \prec \Lambda(\rho)$ is not quite correct too, since they are also in different dimensions. But it's definitely just some condition on both spectrums. I'll check this later.

Comment: It turned out to be harder than I thought. A known majorization relations (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0008073) are not directly applicable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, no, it's not possible. Take for example
$$ \rho = | 0 \rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes |A|}
\hspace{0.2em} \in D(\mathcal{H_A}) $$
For every choice $ \mathcal{H_B}, \mathcal{H_C} $ such that $ \mathcal{H_A} = \mathcal{H_B} \otimes \mathcal{H_C} $ we have
$$ \text{Tr}_C [ \rho ] = | 0 \rangle \langle 0|^{\otimes |B|} $$
so it can not be the case that $ \text{Tr}_C [ \rho ] = \sigma $ for an arbitary fixed $ \sigma \in D(\mathcal{H_B}) $.

Comment: Unfortunately, this argumentation is not correct. The tensor product structure used to define $\rho$ can be different from the one used to factor $A$ into $B$ and $C$. I'll try to comment on this below

Comment: Just read your answer but still can't see how my argument does not provide a valid "counter-example". Could you please provide more details?

Comment: The choice of a tensor product structure for a Hilbert space $\mathcal H_A$ is the choice of an explicit unitary isomorphism $f:\, \mathcal H_A \rightarrow \mathcal H_B \otimes  \mathcal H_C$. In your case, set for simplicity $\mathcal H_A:=\mathbb C^d \otimes \mathbb C^d$. Then, we can arbitrarily "twist" the space by a unitary, e.g. choose $f = CX\cdot H^{\otimes 2}$. Then, the image of $\rho$ under $f$ is the maximally entangled state and the reduced state will be maximally mixed. The question is under which circumstances can we find a suitable $f$ for given $\rho$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for clarifying this!

Comment: Is it like we are allowed to evolve our "initial" state $ \rho $ with arbitrary unitary such that in the final state a part of the system is in $ \sigma $? If so, can we restate the problem as finding a quantum channel $ \Phi \in C(\mathcal{H}_A, \mathcal{H}_B) $ such that $ \Phi(\rho) = \sigma $ and $ rank(J(\Phi)) = \frac{d_A}{d_B} $ ?